# C# Sharepoiint 2010 - How to rename title and description of list or document library

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, rename

I would like change the title (Name) and the description of an existing lists or document Library in more SiteCollection SharePoint. I would like that the name of the list or document library take the name of the site collection.

I create a method for change this but i've an error (

My method :

```
private void RenameLists(SPWeb web)
   {
       this.ExecuteUpgrade(web, () =>
        {
            SPList documentsLibraryList = web.Lists.TryGetList(documentLists.GetDocumentsLibraryName(web));

            if (documentsLibraryList.Title.ToString() == "Document Library")                
            {
                string oldValue = "Document Library";
                string newValue = (web.Title + " Documents").ToString();
                documentsLibraryList.Title.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
                documentsLibraryList.Update();
            }
        });
   }
```

For my method "GetDocumentsLibraryName" :

```
   public static string GetDocumentsLibraryName(SPWeb web)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} Documents", web.Title);
    }
```

But when i debugg, i've an error :

*Message : Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

Any idea ?

Best regards,

Comment: You're trying to grab a list named "[Web Title] Documents", then you're checking to see if it's named "Document Library". Does that seem right to you?

Comment: Yes...
But I've a constant that forced the naming of my list.
And I would replace the name of my list "Document Library" by "[Web Title] Documents".